# Rails 7 API only app requiring session store with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-jwt

I have a new app that I am trying to setup with `devise` and `devise-jwt`.  For some reason my `authenticate_user!` call is causing an error because sessions have been disabled:

> {"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"ActionDispatch::Request::Session::DisabledSessionError: Your application has sessions disabled. To write to the session you must first configure a session store"

**Routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :clients, only: [:show]
      devise_for :users,
             controllers: {
                 sessions: 'users/sessions',
                 registrations: 'users/registrations'
             }
    end
  end
end
```

**User**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :jwt_authenticatable,
         jwt_revocation_strategy: JwtDenylist
end
```

**Controllers:**

```
class API::V1::Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :json
  private
  def respond_with(resource, _opts = {})
    render json: { message: 'Logged.' }, status: :ok
  end
  def respond_to_on_destroy
    current_user ? log_out_success : log_out_failure
  end
  def log_out_success
    render json: { message: "Logged out." }, status: :ok
  end
  def log_out_failure
    render json: { message: "Logged out failure."}, status: :unauthorized
  end
end

class Api::V1::ClientsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_api_v1_user!

    def show
    end
end
```

What else do I need to do?  When I make a request to `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/clients/ID` I'd expect the response to be:

```
=> <html><body>You are being <a href="http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>%
```

rather than this 500 error.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to find a solution on GitHub:

> ```
> config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_interslice_session'
>     config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
>     config.middleware.use config.session_store, config.session_options
> ```

[from this post](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt/issues/235#issuecomment-1116864740)

Answer (score 2):

Careful when enabling session on rails api_only. By default api-only application has session disabled.

By default Warden required session to store. U could simple add to devise.rb the option false to store.

```
config.warden do |manager|
   manager.scope_defaults :user, store: false
end
```

Extra: For who that wants acess sidekiq web, those will have to enable session just for the sidekiq route for example.

```
require 'sidekiq/web'

Sidekiq::Web.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
Sidekiq::Web.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, key: "_interslice_session"

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Sidekiq login auth bonus, of course u can improve the secutiry.
  Sidekiq::Web.use Rack::Auth::Basic do |username, password|
    username == 'username' && password == 'password'
  end

  mount Sidekiq::Web => "/sidekiq"
end
```

Comment: The Warden configuration did the trick. Thanks!