# Getting ActionDispatch::Request::Session::DisabledSessionError after upgrading to rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

I recently upgraded my application to rails 7 and now a bunch of my tests are failing with the below error.

```
ActionDispatch::Request::Session::DisabledSessionError: Your application has sessions disabled. To write to the session you must first configure a session store
```

I am suspecting this has something to do with `devise`.
Below is the code that is causing issues.

```
def login_user(user)
  post "/api/v2/login", :params => { :username => user.username, :password => user.password }
  assert_response :success, response.body
  json = JSON.parse(response.body)
  {:authentication_token => json["user"]["authentication_token"]}
end
```

If I remove the line `config.api_only = true` from the `application.rb` file then the test cases pass without any hitch but I can't really remove that line due to other issues. Does anybody a proper solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a similar question: [Rails 7 API only app requiring session store with Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73487269/rails-7-api-only-app-requiring-session-store-with-devise)

where it's suggested to add following to your `config/application.rb` :

```
config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_interslice_session'
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
    config.middleware.use config.session_store, config.session_options
```

based on [this issue on github](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt/issues/235#issuecomment-1116864740)

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: As someone else wrote in the Github issue you mentioned, for me it was enough to simply remove :timeoutable from devise: https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt/issues/235#issuecomment-1033024421

Answer (score 0):

Adding code below to *config/initializers/devise.rb* works for me.

```
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.scope_defaults :user, store: false
end
```